# leer datos tipo Json desde SQL y enviarlo a un archivo de texto

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

Hola amigos empeze a trabajar en un codigo de C# que tiene que hacer solamente, leer una consulta en mi base de datos (esa consulta me convierte mi tabla a formatos tipo Json) luego el resultado de la consulta tiene que ser enviado a un archivo tipo Json.
Nunca eh trabajado con formatos tipo Json y no se como hacer estas acciones, a ver si alguien me puede dar una mano con esto y explicarme como puedo hacer estas operaciones con este formato.

```
string query="dataJson";
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            using (JsonReader xrdr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
            {
                using (JsonWriter writer = JsonWriter.Create(File.OpenWrite(@"F:\Programador\2 Ano\Semestre_2\C#\Project\dataXml.xml")))
                {
                    writer.WriteNode(xrdr, true);
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(@"F:\Programador\2 Ano\Semestre_2\C#\Project  ", " JSON file created ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Podrías explicarnos el error que te da? Asi podremos ayudarte mejor. un saludo

Comment: me da error de codigo es que eh tratado de hacer un monton de cosas aca y nada todavia no acabo de entender como extraer el formato Json a un archivo